# File.open ignoring path

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm trying to write a file to a specific location.  When I use `File.read("path/to/file")` it opens the correct location but when I use the following, it seems to disregard the path.

```
file_name = timestamp_filename("leads.csv")
dirname = File.dirname("C:/Users/Jordan/Dropbox/list/")

CSV.open(File.join(dirname, file_name), "w") do |csv|
    csv << ["array", "array1"]
end
```

I'm running this from a scheduled task and it inevitably ends up saving it to `C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\VirtualStore\Windows\SysWOW64`.  It also appears that scheduled tasks run their tasks from `C:\Windows\system32`.

How do I make sure this saves to the path desired?

Comment: Looks like `dirname` is being ignored and the file saved in the current directory (and then redirected to the virtual store by Windows).  The first thing to try is using backslashes instead of forward slashes in the file path.

Comment: @HarryJohnston How do I escape them?
EDIT - Got the escape, double backslash.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That was totally it.  Feel free to leave that as the answer and I'll accept!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, the path separator is a backslash rather than a forward slash.  Under some circumstances, Windows will silently convert forward slashes to backslashes, but there are cases where forward slashes won't work.

Apparently, this is one of them!