# windows equivalent of ./ (current directory)

Tags: linux, windows, command-line

On Linux when I want to execute some file and use relative path.

For example I want to do something like this:

```
cd c:\windows
c:\windows>./System32/ipconfig.exe
```

However what I get is an error message telling me that "." has not been found.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A period denotes the current directory in Windows.

For your example you would use the following:

```
c:\> cd c:\windows
c:\Windows> .\System32\ipconfig.exe
```

Alternately, you could forego the .\ and do it like this:

```
c:\Windows> System32\ipconfig.exe
```

Comment: Thanks it seems really simple now

Answer (score 4):

Use the correct slash marks and you should be good. Windows uses backslashes as the directory symbol instead of the forward slash.
The only caveat to this is if you have to change drive letters. The `cd` command will change the working directory, but not the drive. To change drives use `[drive letter][colon]`:

```
C:\Windows>cd P:\XenApp\Utils    
C:\Windows>P:    
P:\XenApp\Utils>
```

Comment: My upvote but few more things: Windows _old_ command lines accepts only `\ `, Windows itself works well with both path separators (`\ ` and `/`). With `cd` you can change also drive using `/d` flag: `cd /d p:/XepApp/Utils`. Hmmm BTW I didn't understand the _caveat_ about drive letters...anyway.

Comment: Thanks Adriano, I hadn't used the /d flag.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: support for forward slashes is *not* comprehensive.  It isn't just the command line.  I strongly recommend that you use backslashes exclusively, to avoid getting caught out, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256655/file-open-ignoring-path

Comment: @harry I strongly think it's a library problem, not an OS problem...OS APIs accept both but not all libraries may correctly accept both when manipulating paths.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: IIRC, there are Win32 APIs that don't accept forward slashes, though I don't recall the details so perhaps I'm misremembering.  Certainly there are parts of Windows, e.g., Explorer, as well as cmd.exe, that don't.  And you can't use them with long path names (paths longer than 260 characters).

Comment: @Harry AFAIK only cmd.exe doesn't support "/" (Explorer does). [Every Windows I/O function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) _should_ support (unless bugs) both separators if, that's right, not using long file names. Command line simply doesn't support it because it'll break 1M programs where "/" indicates a flag and not a file name (I may be wrong but even old MS-DOS 21h functions accepted both...)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: if you run `explorer c:/windows/system32` it won't work.  But it does look as if the Start Menu and Run dialogs accept forward slashes.

Comment: If you run Explorer like that then you are using command line and yes then it does not work