# How to prepend "./" to a path in a platform independent way?

Tags: rust, path, cross-platform, platform, platform-independent

I need to prepend `./` to paths in my code, which I'm currently doing like this:

```rust
let path = Path::new("foo.sol");
let path_with_dot = Path::new("./").join(path);
```

However, I want to maintain compatibility across multiple platforms while adding `./` in front of the path. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to append a path to the path of the current working directory or are you asking if the opposite method of `join` exists, i.e. a method which prepends a path to another path instead of appending it?

Comment: None of the two. I'm asking whether there is some sort of constant in the Rust code that stands for "./". Or a method that prepends "./" without specifically providing "./" as an argument.

Comment: But "./" just refers to the path of the current working directory, so you just want to fetch the path to the current working directory?

Comment: In my application logic, there is a difference between "foo.sol" and "./foo.sol". I already have the former and I simply want to generate the latter by prepending "./". As explained, I already know how to do this, but I was curious if this is a common-enough scenario for Rust to provide some sort of idiomatic functionality for it.

Comment: What's the meaningful difference between "foo.sol" and "./foo.sol" in your application logic?

Comment: I'm writing a CLI tool that manipulates [Solidity](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/) contracts. One of the more popular development frameworks for Solidity, [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/), considers "foo.sol" as a contract imported from "node_modules". Therefore, a Hardhat user needs to prepend "./" in front of the import path in the Solidity contract.

Comment: Okay, so by default Hardhat searches for path-less filenames in the node_modules directory. By prepending the filename with "./" where does Hardhat search for the file then? In the current working directory of the CLI tool, which you're implementing in Rust?

Comment: No, the CLI tool will generate a folder with multiple contracts. Later when one of my users tries to compile the contracts, Hardhat will look into that folder when one of the contracts specifies "./" in front of an import path. I don't see how this is related to my original question though.

Comment: It's relevant because after finally providing all this context I now know [`std::env::current_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_dir.html) won't help you since you're not really working with these Paths as Paths, but more like strings. You're really just asking _"How can I prepend the string "./" to another string?"_ right?

Comment: I am actually working with the paths represented as `PathBuf` in my structs, because I need the path functionality in most of my other code. For instance, I am using the [join](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.join) function a lot. This is why I asked if the `Path` type implements an idiomatic way for prepending "./".

Comment: Okay so then is this [std::path::MAIN_SEPARATOR](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/constant.MAIN_SEPARATOR.html) what you're looking for? You want the path separator to be correct across multiple platforms?

Comment: Yes!! Thanks so much. As per [windows equivalent of ./ (current directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060482/windows-equivalent-of-current-directory), it looks like the dot notation is the same across Unix and Windows, so all I should do is use `MAIN_SEPARATOR` instead of `/`. Thanks for your support!

Comment: In hindsight, "idiomatic" was not the best word to describe my issue. I updated the question title and body to be more specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A platform dependent `const` for path separators is stored at [std::path::MAIN_SEPARATOR](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/constant.MAIN_SEPARATOR.html). You can use this to create platform dependent paths. However, by default the `Path.join` method already uses this `const` so instead of writing:

```rust
let path = Path::new("foo.sol");
let path_with_dot = Path::new("./").join(path);
```

You would just write:

```rust
let path = Path::new("foo.sol");
let path_with_dot = Path::new(".").join(path);
```

And the result will automatically be platform dependent.